# Citrix XenApp 6, cannot connect to licenceserver

Tags: virtualization, licensing, citrix, xenapp, xendesktop

i try to install Citrix XenApp, first install Webinterface und XenApp to one Server and licence-manager to an other server. I can connect to Port 27000 on licenceserver with telnet and can go to Webinterface from licence-server. On the XenApp Server i run Delivery Service Console and check the policy Licenceserverhost and port.

When i connect to XenApp Server i get the message cant connect to licence server. But i don't know why, can anyone tell me how i can debug this. On the licenceserver there are no errorlogs.

Regards
Rene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Message comes because i remove the Startup-License. I upload my own license-file and replace the startup-license. So the connection to license-server does'nt work. When i copy my startup-license back to the license-server all works well.

Regards
Rene